# How do I disassociate an email from my account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, email

When I go to the page that lists my logins, I saw that there was a login associated with my previous email address, so I removed it.

But when I log on to Stack Overflow and click "Forgot password" and enter that previous email address and submit, the email that comes from Stack Overflow to my previous email indicates that my previous email is still associated with my own account.

I expected to either get no email or an error from Stack Overflow stating that there is no account associated with my previous email address on this site.

Comment: The cause of this issue is that due to various legacy reasons, the email address you originally register on the site with is retained internally even after you change it; see [A user's original email address is retained in the system even after they've changed it on all sites (privacy risk, potential Area 51 sync issues)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341932/a-users-original-email-address-is-retained-in-the-system-even-after-theyve-cha). If you want it removed, you'll have to contact SE to request it.

Comment: As the staff member who answered the above post [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341932/a-users-original-email-address-is-retained-in-the-system-even-after-theyve-cha#comment1143993_341933), the fact that the account recovery system still works for a previous email address is a sign of this issue.

Comment: So this means that I can never relinquish control of that email address because then a bad actor and take it and gain some control of my account via that email address?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. As the answer there says, *we* can *clear those obsolete Email fields on a per-user basis if a user is concerned about an old email address being attached to their account. All they need to do is [contact us].*