# (Excessive) login prompt expects my old email even though it's long changed

Tags: support, bug, login, auto-login, email-addresses

I opened a superuser.com link today, and found myself not-logged-in. Already a bit suspicious. Anyway, I enter my email and password at the login prompt - and it fails. I enter my *old* email, which changed months ago, and I *can* login. I navigate to my profile's email settings - and of course I see the *new* email, only.

Questions:

1. Why doesn't the email change effect all relevant accounts and login prompts?
2. Where do I go and change my email for those login prompts?

Comment: It's because there are two separate internal email fields; see [A user's original email address is retained in the system even after they've changed it on all sites (privacy risk, potential Area 51 sync issues)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341932/a-users-original-email-address-is-retained-in-the-system-even-after-theyve-cha). In a comment on the top answer, animuson explains that this is related to the account recovery system still working for old email addresses.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360948/how-do-i-disassociate-an-email-from-my-account

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: I don't mind that my old email address is retained for ... I dunno, reasons; but I still want to be able to log in with my current email.

Comment: you may want to try https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery with your current email.

Answer (score 7):

The issue identified is that you are expecting the email address in your [Email settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current) to be used for login. It is not. That email only affects where notifications are sent to and has absolutely nothing to do with how you login.

What you were looking for was the [My logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) page. This lists all the credentials currently allowed for your account, and any verified emails at the bottom under an "Other" section. Anything listed under "Other" cannot be used for login as they do not have a third-party provider or a password attached to them. If you want an email listed under "Other" to be used for login, just use the "add more logins" button, enter that email again, enter a password, and complete the verification process again. It'll automatically be moved to the "Stack Exchange" section, which is all logins with a password connected and can be used for login.

**Note:** We do not support a "global" password that covers all email addresses connected to your account. Each email address is a separate credential with its own password. Changing the password for one changes the password for *only that one*, not any others.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now that you mention it, I recall having visited that page when I was still logging with SE OpenID. But - after years of not using that, I had forgotten. Anyway, perhaps it would be a good idea to have some text under the notification email to this effect, perhaps with a link to the logins page.

Answer (score 2):

As @RobertLongson suggests, you can enable login using your new address by "recovering" your account using that address:

1. Visit https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery
2. Enter your new email address.
3. Wait for an email in that address
4. In that email, click the "set a password here" link
5. Set the same password you had for the old email, for the new email. (Or choose a different one, always a good idea to rotate passwords occasionally.)

That's it; you can now login with the new address.