# I still have to use my old e-mail address to sign-in, despite my new e-mail address showing up in "Your logins" page

Tags: bug, login

Whenever I try to log-in using my new e-mail address (that is listed in "Your logins" page), I get "No user found with matching email" message.

Update: I have solved the issue on my own and posted the answer below. No other solutions in related questions helped in my case.

Comment: This is probably the reason why: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341933/282094

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though both new and old e-mail addresses were appearing on my Logins page (Settings->ACCESS->Your logins) I wasn't able to log-in with my new e-mail address.

**My solution:**

1. Delete - **all** - logins listed on the abovementioned page, then
2. Use Account recovery (through "Forgot password" link found in the log-in form), then
3. Go to the password reset link sent to your e-mail, then
4. Type in the new password, the procedure is completed.

From now on, I have been able to log-in using my intended e-mail address. Hope this helps someone.